# Could not load file or assembly '' or one of its dependencies. An API call exited abnormally

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a .NET App that I've recently Checked In to Team Foundation Server. Ever since I Checked it in, I get Access Denied to the App folder. I then give security permissions to the impersonated user and receive the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'PMD Image Upload' or one of its
>   dependencies. An API call exited abnormally. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800300FA (STG_E_ABNORMALAPIEXIT))

Comment: The name of the .NET Solution.

Comment: Did you check to make sure that all of the references are valid? Sometimes you lose references when pulling a project down from source control.

Comment: The references were showing access denied, when I turned off the impersonate on the web.config file it worked.

Comment: I don't think we're talking about the same thing. When you expand on the `References` folder in your project, are any of the references invalid?

Comment: None show as invalid. We may be talking about different things. It's now working though. Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Impersonate on the web.config was enabled for a user with no privileges on the debug machine.
Commented out the impersonate and was able to debug the .NET app.

Comment: What if the impersonated user isn't on your local network? e.g. I'm looking at some old legacy code from another company.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is pretty old, but if you need to impersonate on the webserver you also need to award the impersonated user the rights to create/modify the folder "Temporary ASP.NET Files" in Windows\Microsoft.NET\"TheUsedFrameworkVersion".

Comment: on my Win 2008 R2 server, it was this path: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`  (and not the `Framework64` path) - ymmv

Comment: I also needed to add full permissions for the impersonated user under my local `%TEMP%` folder

Comment: In my case, it was also the above permission issue. My error message (just in case, someone googles for it) was "**System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, Version=0.86.0.518, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b03e6acf1164f73' or one of its dependencies. An API call exited abnormally. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800300FA (STG_E_ABNORMALAPIEXIT))**". I did  not use IIS impersonation but rather [my own impersonation class](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User).

Answer (score 8):

The impersonate user should be given privileges to the solution files as well as the temp asp.net files for the solution, usually located in the following directory:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Where "Framework" could be "Framework64" and "v4.0.30319" may be another .Net version number.

Answer (score 0):

Bruno is correct.  Disabling impersonation worked for me as well.  If you don't have impersonate in your webconfig, and you're still having trouble.  If you're running IIS 7.5 check your Application Pool.  Sometimes it can be set to impersonate.

Look under [*Advanced Settings > Process Model > Identity*]

You'll want to set it to [*ApplicationPoolIdentity*].

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="divWindowMain">
   <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
       <Services></Services>
   </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
</div>
```